# Google Analytics V3 API: Java method to include dimension and metrics

Tags: java, api

I am trying to find right method in GA V3 analytics API to get dimension and metrics.

The current method:

```
return analytics.data().ga()
                .get(String, String, String,String)
                .execute();
```

Doesn't allow to set dimension as part of the query.

Answer (score 2):

I found the format in another sample provided in GA documentation:
`return analytics.data().ga()
                       .get(<String>,<String>,<String>,<String>,)
                       .setDimensions(<String>)
                       .setSort(<String>)
                       .setFilters(<String>)
                       .setMaxResults(<int>)
                       .execute();`